# How do I best delete a line from a .csv file I have added into with C++ using an id value?

Tags: c++

I am in the middle of coding a management system with a Greek God theme. I have been able to successfully insert new gods into a .csv file, and now I want to delete entries I have made. Below is my code I am working with

```
void deleteGod()
    {
        system("clear");
        char matchId[6];
        fstream file, newFile;
        int found = 0;
        cout << "\t\t\t Delete a God \t\t\t\n";
        // opening the gods file, ios::in reads, ios:out opora
        file.open("gods.csv", ios::in);
        if(!file)
        {
            cout << "\n\t\t\t The gods are at it again...the file is lost";
            file.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter the god ID of the god you are sending to Tartarus:";
            cin >> matchId;
            newFile.open("newGods.csv", ios::app | ios::out);
            file >> godId >> godName >> romanName;
            while (!file.eof())
            {
                printf("while loop not end of file");
                if(matchId != godId)
                {
                    newFile << " " << godId << " " << godName << " " << romanName << "\n";
                    printf("new file");
                }
                else
                {
                    found ++;
                    printf("deleted else statement");
                    cout << "\t\t God was banished";
                }
                file >> godId >> godName >> romanName;
            }
            newFile.close();
            file.close();
            remove("gods.csv");
            rename("newGods.csv", "gods.csv");
        }
    }
```

I am not sure the best way to compare the matchId input from the user to the godId value that was already set in the .csv

I am guessing I also need to getline() my the entry strings as a better way to delete the entry, but I am not sure. I am new to C++ and this is my first project working with it. Is this a good starting approach? Suggestions and tips are helpful.

I was expecting for this to delete the entry I had made in the .csv file.

I have been trying to use a vector and index the entry, and get the [0] and compare that with the matchId, but I felt too confused and decided to go this route instead.

Comment: Assuming each entry is in a separate line (1) create an output file  (2) read a line (3) if the line doesn't contain the id, write it to the output file  (3) repeat 2 and 3 until end of input file is reached (4) close the files (5) delete the input file  (6) move or rename the output file to what was the input file

Comment: Best approach, read all gods (or whatever each line of the .csv is) into a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of struct at the start of your program, manipulate the contents of the vector while your code is running, write the new file out when you are done (or you can write the file at any intermediate juncture you like). You don't want to manipulate the file, that's just a recipe for a corrupt file unless done exactly right.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Reading the entire file into a `vector` is not always the *best* option if there is a large number of entries involved.

Comment: There are caveats and corner cases to every method. However, without a statement that this beginner exercise involves millions (billions) of lines, there is no reason to presume it would.

Comment: @Peter I feel like I am following your steps. The problem i am running into now is getting stuck in the if statement, matchId != godId, i changed the data types to ints to be easier to work with.

I'm not sure why I am getting stuck in an infinite loop, any thoughts?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you help point me in the right direction? Is there a line of my code i am writing incorrectly? I've been stuck on this all day.

Comment: @JoshDewhurst well, for starters, you should change `file >> godId >> godName >> romanName; while (!file.eof()) { ... file >> godId >> godName >> romanName; }` to `while (file >> godId >> godName >> romanName) { ... }` instead, and also remove the leading `" "` from `newFile << " " << ...` Beyond that, you will need to show your actual `gods.csv` file. If it is an actual CSV format, then you are ignoring any syntax elements *between* the values (commas, tabs, quotes, etc), which is likely to get your reading code into a bad state..